# Is there a way to return an array of each entry in database under a key?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database and I have two different tables.

One is for affiliates and the structure looks like this:

```
Table1
| id  | name        | code     | color   |
|----------------------------------------|
| 1   | First Name  | ARC      | #fff    |
| 2   | Second Name | ETF      | #000    |
| 3   | Third Name  | DRC      | #fefef4 |


Table2
| id  | created              | affiliate   |
|------------------------------------------|
| 1   | 2022-02-03 13:48:58  | ARC         |
| 2   | 2022-02-04 13:48:58  | ETF         |
| 3   | 2022-02-05 13:48:58  | DRC         |
| 4   | 2022-02-06 13:48:58  | ARC         |
| 5   | 2022-02-24 13:48:58  | ETF         |
| 6   | 2022-03-03 13:48:58  | DRC         |
| 7   | 2022-03-04 13:48:58  | ARC         |
| 8   | 2022-03-07 13:48:58  | ETF         |
| 9   | 2022-03-09 13:48:58  | DRC         |
```

I am currently making a query to Inner Join the values on the affiliate column so that I can get the color and name specific to each affiliate.

The result looks like this

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [created] => 2022-02-03 13:48:58
    [affiliate] => ARC
    [name] => First Name
    [color] => #fff
),
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [created] => 2022-02-04 13:48:58
    [affiliate] => ETF
    [name] => Second Name
    [color] => #000
),
Array
(
    [id] => 3
    [created] => 2022-02-05 13:48:58
    [affiliate] => DRC
    [name] => Third Name
    [color] => #fefef4
),
Array
(
    [id] => 4
    [created] => 2022-02-06 13:48:58
    [affiliate] => ARC
    [name] => First Name
    [color] => #fff
),
...
```

It returns an array with key, value pairs corresponding to the column and row value present in the database.

What I am trying to achieve is, get a result something similar to this fashion

```
Array
(
[ARC] => Array (
                Array (
                   [id] => 1
                   [created] => 2022-02-06 13:48:58
                   [affiliate] => ARC
                   [name] => First Name
                   [color] => #fff
               ),
                Array (
                   [id] => 4
                   [created] => 2022-02-06 13:48:58
                   [affiliate] => ARC
                   [name] => First Name
                   [color] => #fff
               )
            ),
[ETF] => Array (
                Array (
                   [id] => 2
                   [created] => 2022-02-06 13:48:58
                   [affiliate] => ETF
                   [name] => Second Name
                   [color] => #000
               )
             ),
[DRC] => Array (
                Array (
                   [id] => 3
                   [created] => 2022-02-06 13:48:58
                   [affiliate] => DRC
                   [name] => Third Name
                   [color] => #fefef4
               )
             )
)
```

Is it possible to achieve something like this from an SQL query directly, or would it be easier just to make something server side to process the data in this format?

Comment: You must already be processing the data _somehow_, otherwise you would not have the arrays you have shown us to begin with - a SQL query _on its own_, does not result in "arrays". Trying to get any such PHP-internal data structure directly from a query, is pretty much impossible, IMHO. Looping over the records your query returns and creating the desired structure in PHP, is fairly trivial.

Comment: I just printed them out in PHP so I can show you the results. That is true, looping and getting the desired structure is trivial and is easily achievable, but I thought there was another way to do it.

Comment: You may be able to achieve the expected outcome through the use of mysql's json functions, but you would be pushing completely unrelated transformation tasks into mysql.

Comment: I voted to close this as a duplicate of a question I answered yesterday. The query is not exactly the same as yours, but the technique is the same. I do agree with the other comments that it's better to write a simple SQL query, and then process the results using code.